# Restrict external users to access bot from Channels like Teams

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a custom MS Teams Message extension app in Teams and successfully published that in Azure, but i have noticed that Azure web app bot where i have added Teams as a Channel, i can access the app out side the organization also.
So is there a way i can restrict it to my AD users and in AD also i need to provide access with specific AD groups.
If I copy the URL and try to open with user not in AD still i can access it.

[image]

Comment: The "Open in Teams" link includes authentication to authenticate you with the bot. Having that work is expected behavior.

Comment: In this case, you can implement the authentication for you bot/Messaging Extension and make sure your bot/ME is configured for single tenant only.
As per my knowledge, you can not restrict uses to access it for AD Groups.

Comment: @Mayuresh Jaiswal -Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: I'm working on the existing bot and it seems it a multi tenant bot, so i want to authenticate the user before accessing it.

Comment: Have you implemented the bot auth?
if you  want to restrict it to single tenant, you can do configuration for it.
Reference Document:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can implement the authentication for you bot/Messaging Extension and make sure your bot/ME is configured for single tenant only.you can not restrict uses to access it for AD Groups